# Improving code with reflection and generics

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dry, code-readability

With the following code, how could I improve its readability using reflection and generics?
It's a lot of repeated code, but I'm new to these concepts.
"dl" is an interface but I'm not sure why I can't get access to the properties I want with .getType().getProperties(), it returns an empty list.

```
if (entity == "SERVICE")
{
    if (filter == "Active == 1")
    {
        foreach (var service in dl.Services.List().Where(x => x.Active).OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            tmpReturn.Add(service.ID, service.Name);

        return tmpReturn;
    }

    foreach (var service in dl.Services.List().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        tmpReturn.Add(service.ID, service.Name);

    return tmpReturn;
}

if (entity == "CAMPAIGN")
{
    if (filter == "Active == 1")
    {
        foreach (var campaign in dl.Campaigns.List().Where(x => x.Active).OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            tmpReturn.Add(campaign.ID, campaign.Name);

        return tmpReturn;
    }

    foreach (var campaign in dl.Campaigns.List().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        tmpReturn.Add(campaign.ID, campaign.Name);

    return tmpReturn;
}

if (entity == "AGENT")
{
    if (condition == "Active != ")
    { 
        if (value == "1")
        { 
            foreach (var agent in dl.Agents.List().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
                tmpReturn.Add(agent.ID, agent.Name);

            return tmpReturn;
        }

        foreach (var agent in dl.Agents.List().Where(x => x.Active).OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            tmpReturn.Add(agent.ID, agent.Name);

        return tmpReturn;
    }
    else if (condition == "Active == ")
    {
        if (value == "1")
        {
            foreach (var agent in dl.Agents.List().Where(x => x.Active).OrderBy(x => x.Name))
                tmpReturn.Add(agent.ID, agent.Name);

            return tmpReturn;
        }

        foreach (var agent in dl.Agents.List().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            tmpReturn.Add(agent.ID, agent.Name);

        return tmpReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: " but I'm not sure why I can't get access to the properties I want with .getType().getProperties()" - because GetType() will always return you the concrete type, not the interface? but: what is it that you're actually trying to do here? would a `switch` statement work? reflection is rarely a good option

Comment: Probably encapsulate the repeated part into a method, like addItem(), that would have the foreach inside, and would access the right property from the interface using the variable entity. Like dl.(variable)(this part using reflection to get it).myLinqQuery.                          In summary it is a lot of repeated code and that's what I'm trying to avoid, so i thought  reflection would help me to build this method.

Comment: You don't need reflection or generics. Just use a pattern. Look into conditional to polymorphism.

Comment: Generics, maybe. Reflection is what happens when all else fails. Trust me, we're way more likely to improve our code by figuring out how *not* to use reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the different entities do not implement a common interface, we use [ValueTuples](http://.Select(x%20=%20(x.ID,%20x.Name,%20x.Active));) as intermediate result. I am not sure what the ID type is. I am assuming `int` here, but you can change this easily.

```cs
IEnumerable<(int ID, string Name, bool Active)> source;
bool filterByActive;
switch (entity) {
    case "SERVICE":
        source = dl.Services.List().Select(x => (x.ID, x.Name, x.Active));
        filterByActive = filter == "Active == 1";
        break;
    case "CAMPAIGN":
        source = dl.Campaigns.List().Select(x => (x.ID, x.Name, x.Active));
        filterByActive = filter == "Active == 1";
        break;
    case "AGENT":
        source = dl.Agents.List().Select(x => (x.ID, x.Name, x.Active));
        filterByActive = condition == "Active != " && value != "1" ||
                         condition == "Active == " && value == "1";
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
if (filterByActive) {
    source = source.Where(x => x.Active);
}
return source
    // .OrderBy(x => x.Name)       Not for Dictionary!
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.Name);
```

The idea is that we return an enumeration representing the data source and a Boolean telling whether we have to filter in a switch statement. All the other things can then be performed on this data source.

We can compose the enumerable by applying the `Where` separately.

Using the LINQ extension method `ToDictionary()` instead of the addition of single elements in a loop simplifies things further. Note that if you are adding things to a dictionary, sorting the items has no effect.

Comment: I don't think the cast is possible, I've updated the question with more info, sorry :\

Comment: Okay. I am unifying the different DTO types through a temporary tuple now.

Comment: And, btw., your `IAgentDAL` interface does not have a `List` method with no arguments as you have used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need reflection or generics:
(I'm not writing types in the following code snippet as I can't always infer them from your code.)

```
List getTmpReturn(list, bool isActive){
    if (isActive){
        foreach (var item in list.List().Where(x => x.Active).OrderBy(x => x.Name))
             tmpReturn.Add(item.ID, item.Name);
    }
    else {
        foreach (var item in list.List().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            tmpReturn.Add(item.ID, item.Name);
    }
    return tmpReturn;
}

switch(entity):
    case "SERVICE":
        return getTmpReturn(dl.Services, filter == "Active == 1");
    case "CAMPAIGN":
        return getTmpReturn(dl.Campaigns, filter == "Active == 1");
    case "AGENT":
        bool isActive = (condition == "Active != " && value != "1") || (condition == "Active == " && value == "1");
        return getTmpReturn(dl.Agents, isActive);
```